# How can I declare a long-lived db context for my background tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, .net-core

I have several background tasks like the following

```
public class SportsbookEventService : BackgroundService
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        public SportsbookEventService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ILogger<SportsbookEventService> logger) : base(scopeFactory, logger)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                    timer.Restart();
                    var tasks = new List<Task>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {
                        tasks.Add(Fanduel.ProcessSchedule(SportLeagues.MLB, logger, dbContext));
                    }
                    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    timer.Stop();
                    logger.LogWarning(timer.Elapsed.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff"));

                    await Task.Delay(1, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }
  
    }
```

This takes about 1 second to run and instantly fires off again.  Because of this, the overhead of creating a new `dbContext` each time, can have a large relative overhead.  How would I be able to add in a long-lived `dbContext` to this `BackgroundService`?

Comment: What about having a private read-only dbcontext through the constructor?, I  believe that will help you to use the same dbcontext again and again.

Comment: *Contexts are expected to be short lived and discarded*. See [Is DbContext an expensive operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282979/is-dbcontext-an-expensive-operation).

Comment: When people believe they're enhancing their performance by leaving a database connection, the minimal overhead produced often creates an assortment of other issues.  Even if you analyze the garbage collector, you will see that when IDispose is called on even ADO.NET it is not that much being cleaned up from the short lived instance.

Comment: You can add dbContext to singletone services, and it will work, but it is a very bad idea.

Comment: If you want to reuse contexts / connections, just `.AddDbContextPool(...)`